# React map the array into dropdown problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Dialog.js

```
  const Dialog = ({label, onClose, open}) => {
     handleSubmit=()=>{};
        return (
         <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {() => (
           <Dialog 
            onClose={onClose}
            open={open}
            title={() => label}
            content={() => <RatingTable />}}
            action={() => {}}
           />
          )}
         </Form>
        )
    }
```

RatingTable.js

```
const RatingTable = ()=> {
  return(
   <table>
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <header1>
        <header2>
      </tr>
     <thead>
     <tbody>
      {PeopleList.map(People=>(
        <PeopleRow {...people} id={people.id} name={people.name}>
      ))}
     </tbody>
   </table>
)}
```

PeopleList.js

```
const List = [
{id:1, name:"jack", sex:"male", age:23},
{id:2, name:"marry", sex:"female", age:18},
{id:3, name:"paul", sex:"male", age:12},
{id:4, name:"katty", sex:"female", age:20}
]

 const PeopleArray = List.reduce(
 (acc, {age}) =>{
   acc.push(age);
  return acc;
  },[]);
```

PeopleRow.js

```
const PeopleRow = name => {
 return (
  <tr>
   <td>
    <TextField value={name}>
   </td>
   <td>
    <DropDownField source={PeopleList}>
   </td>
  </tr>
 )
}
```

so like ideally I want to the `PeopleArray` which is the age array showed in my `DropDownFiled` component, but some how the age value didn't show in the drop down[image] instead, it only show the text select 4 times.I want to make the dropdown which can select from those 4 ages that in the `peopleArray`.

Comment: Can you share the CodePen link for your project?

Answer (score 0):

In RatingTable.js file, you misspelled the term `people` with `People`.

```
const RatingTable = ()=> {
return(
   <table>
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <header1>
        <header2>
      </tr>
     <thead>
     <tbody>
      {PeopleList.map((people) => (           // Change this, replace `People` with `people`
        <PeopleRow {...people} id={people.id} name={people.name}>
      ))}
     </tbody>
   </table>
)}
```